# Cursor got deselected when I switch Visual Studio 2022 to another application. How can I solve it?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I code in Visual Studio 2022 and switch to another app (for example, when I'm watching a tutorial and coding simultaneously), I have to click on the location where I want to write my code upon returning to Visual Studio. The cursor automatically deselects itself.

I tried going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General and checked and deselected various options, but it didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you need to click at the cursor location? What happens if you just click on Visual Studio's title bar?

Comment: yes i need to click the cursor's location every time i switch apps. here is one more interesting thing. suppose i am using vs and it is placed in the first position in the task bar. and any other app (for me it's chrome) is in the 2nd place. windows has a shortcut that we can switch app which are placed in taskbar with shortcuts by using windows button + 1/2/3 (which represents the order of the apps based on their serial). if i minimize vs by pressing windows+1 to watch chrome, then the cursor is in it's place. but when i press windows+2 to open chrome the cursor get deselected.

Comment: yesterday i saw a preview update of vs 2022, i updated it, in the preview version it's solved.